# Split column into segments by groups of start/stop intervals

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a very simple data frame where ID is a number sequence and there are multiple groups, where beginnings/endings are denominated with start/stop:

```
ID = c(1:20)
group = c(NA,1,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,2,NA,NA,NA,NA) %>% as.factor()
type = c(NA,"start",NA,NA,NA,"stop",NA,NA,NA,"start",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,"stop",NA,NA,NA,NA) %>% as.factor()

df = data.frame(ID,group,type)
head(df)

   ID group  type
1   1  <NA>  <NA>
2   2     1 start
3   3  <NA>  <NA>
4   4  <NA>  <NA>
5   5  <NA>  <NA>
6   6     1  stop
```

I would like to fill the NAs in group with the adjacent values and split the data frame into segments between the start/stop intervals:

```
   ID group  type
1   2     1 start
2   3     1  <NA>
3   4     1  <NA>
4   5     1  <NA>
5   6     1  stop
6  10     2 start
7  11     2  <NA>
8  12     2  <NA>
9  13     2  <NA>
10 14     2  <NA>
11 15     2  <NA>
12 16     2  stop
```

If the missing values in group could be replaced, then the data frame could simply be reduced to values in group that are not NAs. I have looked at `tidyr::fill()`, but cannot find a good solution. Any suggestions will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `fill` the 'group' column to replace the `NA` elements with the preceding non-NA elements, `filter` out the NA rows based on the 'group' values that are still NA, grouped by 'group' `slice` the rows until the 'stop' value in the 'type' column (assuming one 'start/stop' combination per 'group')

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  fill(group) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(group)) %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  slice(seq_len(which(type == "stop"))) 
# A tibble: 12 x 3
# Groups:   group [2]
#      ID group type 
#   <int> <fct> <fct>
# 1     2 1     start
# 2     3 1     <NA> 
# 3     4 1     <NA> 
# 4     5 1     <NA> 
# 5     6 1     stop 
# 6    10 2     start
# 7    11 2     <NA> 
# 8    12 2     <NA> 
# 9    13 2     <NA> 
#10    14 2     <NA> 
#11    15 2     <NA> 
#12    16 2     stop
```